# Finding a word for an example

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

My husband very often responds with obvious responses that I just want to roll my eyes and I need to find out why he does it or at the least tolerate it if I know what he's doing.  He has many good qualities, but he's been doing this since I've known him.
Example:  We're in the middle of renovating a room in our house and I reached out to flooring company from the other side of the country who had a product that I was interested in, so I supplied my phone number in an e-form.  We weren't quite ready to reach out since we're awaiting our interior decorator to get back to us on the flooring design, but the company was trying to get ahold of me via text/calling, doing his job reaching out several times more than I thought, but I hadn't responded back - my bad, so I asked my husband if we should call back and get some information on the flooring product they had to offer.  My husband said **"he's trying to get back to you because he wants to get our business."**  That was when I rolled my eyes, saying, of course!  What I was really getting to w/my question was when do we want to consult with the company. Do I need to be more specific moving forward to avoid obvious answers like this?   Anyway, I may have gone way to long on this explanation, but I'd to know why he does this and more importantly, is there a word for it.   He does this a lot to a lot of people in many different conversations.  I think people tolerate it, because he is such a thoughtful  & nice man.

Comment: Can your question be summarised as: what is the word for remarks that are so obvious that they are pointless and, therefore, annoying? Or is there something else that the word is supposed to capture?

Comment: In UK English there is a phrase "stating the blindingly obvious" which is what your husband appears to be doing. There are ruder versions like "stating the bleeding obvious" but the first one is the most universally acceptable, even if it's a minced oath version of the first one. I don't know whether either of these phrases exists in US English but I'd be surprised if it turns out that there isn't and equivalent of one of them at least.